# Why does iTunes only play one song?

Tags: itunes

So here's what my iTunes looks like right now:

[image: iTunes screenshot]

Nothing on this screen does what I'd expect, which may or may not be a problem with my expectations.

1. Why does double clicking on a track play only that track and then stop, rather than playing the album from there?
2. Why does clicking the play button next to "Demon Days" do nothing? What is the button for?
3. Why does clicking the arrow icon to the right of "Demon Days" and then choosing "Add to Up Next" add nothing to Up Next?

Can't make head nor tail of iTunes these days. Am I just getting old?

Comment: I don't have little cloud icons to the right like you do. Perhaps iTunes lost access to the filesystem where your library was, and is offering to download prior purchases, and it is for that reason it doesn't play/download them all in sequence?

Comment: The cloud icons indicate the tracks are "in the cloud" with iTunes Match. Well spotted, but it behaves just the same with albums that have been downloaded.

Comment: Click the "play" icon next to the album title to play the entire album.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason your songs are greyed out. That's why it doesn't work a you expect it.

Try following : Select all these songs then under right mouse click => Check selection.

Comment: Really? They all play fine (but one-by-one) if I double click on them.

Comment: Oh! I just selected them all and chose "Check Selection" on the right-click menu and now they're all black! Thanks so much!

Comment: That is completely bizarre. There are no check marks anywhere in this UI (and no such thing as a check mark in British English anyway). iTunes is a truly awful piece of software.

Comment: They are displayed under the songs menu! (yes they could have done it better !)

Comment: Yeah I just went into the songs list to check my whole music collection. Haven't been into the songs list for years.